# Chronograf UI to display all the points for the same time interval

Tags: influxdb, chronograf

I am trying to show a tabular format for all the data I have in my influxdb on chronograf.

As I have multiple points (data) at the same timestamp it displays only one data for a single timestamp.

I want to show all the data on the chronograf irrespective of the same time. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Example:

Measurement name: sample

```
time     field1  filed2      tag1        tag2
t11       f11     f12       tag11       tag12
t11       f11     f12       tag21       tag12
t11       f11     f12       tag31       tag12
t12       f21     f22       tag11       tag22
```

I am trying query on chronograf: SELECT filed1,filed2, tag1 from sample WHERE tag2='tag12'

The table shows the below data:

```
t11  f11 f12 tag11
```

I am expecting I am output to be:

```
t11 f11 f12 tag11
t11 f11 f12 tag21
t11 f11 f12 tag31
```

Note: Same command gives me correct output on the influxdb cli.

Thank You in advance

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question accordingly. When asking a question it is better to *show what research you have done* into your problem and post any *code* or *errors* if it applies.